# Eve sub resources and embedding resource serialization

Tags: python, eve

I'm using Eve RESTful API framework

I'm trying to do a simple thing since a few weeks, but I don't manage.
I just want to have a list of places, and a list of commentaries, as described in my settings.py as below :

settings.py:

```
comments_schema = {
                 'spot_id': {
                         'type': 'string',
                         'required': True
                 },
                 'description': {
                         'required': True,
                         'type': 'string',
                         'empty': False,
                         'maxlength': 250
                 }
 }

 comments = {
         'url': 'spots/<regex("[a-f0-9]{24}"):place_id>/comments',
         'item_title': 'comment',
         'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
         'schema': comments_schema
 }

 places_schema = {
         'name': {
                 'required': True,
                 'type': 'string',
                 'empty': False,
                 'maxlength': 60
         },
         'description': {
                 'required': True,
                 'type': 'string',
                 'empty': False,
                 'maxlength': 250
         },
         'commentaries': {
                 'type': 'objectid',
                 'data_relation': {
                         'resource': 'comments',
                         'field': '_id',
                         'embeddable': True
                 }
          }
  }

  places = {
         'item_title': 'place',
         'resource_methods': ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
         'item_methods': ['GET', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'],
         'schema': places_schema
 }

 DOMAIN = {
         'places': places,
         'comments': comments
 }
```

I can POST places, I can POST comments, but when I GET places I do not have comments nested in. And when I GET comments, it's a empty list that is returned.

I checked my Mongo comments collections and I correctly can see my comments. That means they are correctly inserted, but not correctly retrieved.

I know I'm confusing [Sub resources](http://python-eve.org/features.html#subresources) and [Embedded resource serialization](http://python-eve.org/features.html#embedded-resource-serialization) a bit. If I'm not wrong, sub-resources allows you to manage a resource as a sub resource (I mean, using URLs like places//comments for POST) and embedding resource serialization allows you to get every linked comments nested in the place.

But please, help me to understand why I can't simply create places, create comments and then GET all my places with nested commentaries in.

Thanks,

MC

Comment: I am not sure I understand what your design goal is. Can multiple comments be posted for the same place? Do you really need an alternate endpoint for comments? Why not directly embed them in the `places` document?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the answer late, I was stuck at the hospital...
Yes, multiple comments can be posted for the same place.
I just want to be ableto add/edit/delete comments.
In fact, no, you're right, I don't necessary need and altenative comments endpoint. But It will be easier for editing comment with it i guess.
I want to embed comments directly in the place doc, but it doesn't work for me :(

I mean when I get places, comments are not embedded in.